# Print Matlab figures whose axis ratio the same as in screen

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having problems printing a .jpg figure that keeps the same appearance as seen on screen. The printed figure looks stretched.
Any helps ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to use this line:

```
 set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```

to make sure Matlab does not resize the figure. If it does not work please show the code you use.

Comment: Great then glad to help!